# Pushing to GitHub

Tags: git

I'm trying to push a project to GitHub and am following their instructions, posted below:

```
mkdir PyPong # Skipped mkdir and cd steps
cd PyPong # Git bash path already set
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:[username redacted]/PyPong.git
git push -u origin master # ERROR!
```

I've already committed all my files, created my RSA key for SSH, and configured my API token. However, I still get the following problems in bash:

```
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'git@github.com/[username redacted]/PyPong.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have created the repository on github?

Comment: Yes; on my GitHub homepage it's listed under my repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is there in your `.git/config` as url for origin?

The error seems to suggest that the url is `git@github.com/user/PyPong.git` while it should be `git@github.com:user/PyPong.git`

Comment: I don't know how to check up on this. What's the bash command? (As an aside, I thought the conversion from `:` to `/` was fishy, but I didn't know if it had anything to do with my error.)

Comment: @Edwin Either run `git config remote.origin.url` or `vi .git/config` and see `[remote "origin"]`

Comment: I tried running both. `git config remote.origin.url` returns nothing, while `vi .git/config` returns `ERROR: Unable to swap file for ".git/config", recovery impossible.`

Comment: @Edwin - Otherwise try `cat .git/config`

Comment: Should've mentioned I already tried that and got `cat: .git/config: No such file or directory` for my efforts.

Comment: @Edwin - are you trying from repo root? Your repo should have the config in `.git/config`. Find that file. I cannot be of much more help. Hope you get your problem solved.